# Jpql LEFT JOIN FETCH with where null condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, left-join, jpql

User can have many phones. I want to return all users with they phones that endContract field of phone IS NULL;

My JPQL query:

```
SELECT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.phones p WHERE p.endContract IS NULL
```

And this query is not working as I expected:

a) When user doesn't have any phone query returns only user data with empty collection of phones which is ok

b) When user have multiple phones with endContract is NULL then I'm getting all correct data

c) The problem is when my User have multiple phones but none of the endContract of phone  is NULL. Then I'm getting no result from query, 
but I'm expecting to get the same result as in a) scenario

Comment: "User have multiple phones but none of the endContract of phone is NULL" - this statement negates your conditional clause `WHERE p.endContract IS NULL`, so your c scenario result is working as expected.

Comment: So how to rewrite the query in order to get empty collection when all phones have endContract not null. I want to have the same result as in scenario a)

Comment: You can't have an empty collection if the user does have phones, regardless of the state of `endContract`.